# iOS development forums?

Tags: ios, development, developer-program

Can I access and post on the official Apple iOS developer forums without the 99dollars subscription ?

Comment: One of the best forums is [Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com), and not just because I'm a moderator there. The forums are active and full of working developers. We make an effort to answer every question and there are tons of great tutorials - usually a new one every week. Please take a look!

Comment: Take a look at [iOS Developer Forums](http://iosdeveloperforums.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. To post on or view the developer forums, you must be a paid member.

http://developer.apple.com/devforums/

> The Apple Developer Forums are available to iOS, Mac and Safari Developer Program members.